# Possible Database hiccup caused lost acceptance?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822262/sorting-a-datagridview-by-datagridviewcomboxboxcolumn/1822509#1822509) answer accepted and the OP added a comment explaining what it was in the answer that helped him.

Seconds after my reply comment I then navigated to the main page and my rep had dropped by 15 - I had lost the accepted tick and the comment from the OP was gone.

Exactly what I did was leave the question open, then click on the question title to refresh - it was then that I saw the acceptance and the OPs comment.

Perhaps the OP just decided that I wasn't so helpful (fair enough), but I thought I'd highlight it here in case there is actually a bug.

Also - is meta actually the correct forum for bug reports?

Comment: Yes, this is an appropriate place for bug reports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doubt it was a bug - more likely the OP reversed their decision that you provided the answer for their question, and deleted the comment.  Happened to me once or twice.

Comment: Yeah - I hope that's that case. Thought it worth highlighting though. Does SO keep track of the history of acceptance and comments?

Comment: Best place to look is the **Activity** tab in your profile, beneath the "About Me" writeup.

Comment: That was the first place a looked - it doesn't show anything of relevance. I know it shows when one of my answers is accepted, but what about one is accepted and then that is reversed?

Comment: @David Hall - unfortunately there's no indication of a removed acceptance. You can only really tell if the original acceptance was recent and you can spot it missing from the activity list. There are questions here on meta about getting notification of this.